# How to get the jqwidget grid filter textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqxgrid

I am using jqwidget grid (jqxgrid).I want to  get the object of Filter textbox . 
[Here is jqwidget grid link.](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/filterrow.htm)
Can any body help me how do i get this name textbox filter object.Thanks Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by after applying filter and then refreshing the grid using $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('refreshfilterrow');